# issue with paper menu fired on-iron-selected event

Tags: polymer-1.0, polymer-starter-kit

I would like to ask your help on this, because I didn't find a solution for this and I tried to find answers on Google and I didn't find anything.
I have a project with **Polymer Starter Kit**, in the Index.html I'm using a `<paper-menu>`. I would like to fire the event on-iron-selected event. This is what I did:

```
<paper-menu attr-for-selected="data-route" selected="[[route]]" id="general_menu" class="hiddenStruct" on-iron-select="handleItemSelect">
```

My problem is that I really don't know where I have to implement the event. I tried to do something like this in the **app.js**:

```
handleItemSelect: function(event, detail, sender){alert("Entro");}
```

But I got error in the console.
Can anyone of you help me to know in what place I have to implement this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this is:
Implement the following code inside the the app.js:

```
(function(document) { 
    app.handleItemSelect = function(event, detail, sender){
      alert("Example");
    };
})(document);
```

I hope this helped to somebody else with the same problem.